# How to fix the error 'You cannot render this Element if it is not in a Figure' when saving a map as an HTML file using folium?

Tags: python-3.x, folium

I am trying to save a map as an HTML file using the save method of the Map object from the folium library. However, I am getting the error "You cannot render this Element if it is not in a Figure." I have tried using the webbrowser module to open the HTML file in a web browser, but I am still getting the same error. How can I fix this issue and save the map as an HTML file?

```
import psycopg2
import folium
import folium.plugins

# Connect to the database
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", user="sde", password="xxxx", dbname="data")

# Create a cursor to execute queries
cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute the query to retrieve the data
cur.execute("SELECT y, x, type FROM cone")

# Fetch the data
data = cur.fetchall()

# Set the center of the map to the correct x and y values
y, x, _ = data[3]  # Retrieve the first row of data and assign the x and y values to the x and y variables

# Create a folium.FeatureGroup object to hold the markers
feature_group = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Cones")

# Set the center of the map to the correct lat and lon values
map = folium.Map(location=[y, x], zoom_start=8)



# Iterate through the data and add markers to the map and the feature group
for datapoint in data:
    y, x, type = datapoint
    marker = folium.Marker([float(y), float(x)], popup=type)
    marker.add_to(map)
    feature_group.add_child(marker)

# Create a search bar using the feature group as the layer
search = folium.plugins.Search(layer=feature_group, search_label='Search for cones',
                               search_zoom=12, search_marker=True)
search.add_to(map)

import webbrowser

# Save the map as an HTML file
map.save("map.html")

# Open the map in a web browser
webbrowser.open("map.html")
```

I am getting the error "You cannot render this Element if it is not in a Figure." I have tried using the webbrowser module to open the HTML file in a web browser, but I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You should add the featuregroup to the map, that’s missing currently. Then add the markers only to the featuregroup, not also to the map.

The result is: map > featuregroup > markers.